# the code ignore the if/else statement in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I don't know if you can help me... I have a problem with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# = 0 ]; then
    awk '{for (x=5; x<=NF; x++) {printf "%s ", $x } printf "\n" }' affy.txt
else
    columns=""
    for i in $@; do
        if [ $i = "-g" ]; then
            word=$2
            is_there_g="True"
            break
        else
            is_there_g="False"
        fi
        columns+="$i,"
        shift
    done
    columns=${columns%,}
    if [ $is_there_g="False" ]; then
        cat affy.txt | cut -d" " -f$columns 
    else
        grep $word affy.txt | cut -d" " -f$columns
    fi
fi

echo $is_there_g
```

So, there's a problem obtaining the results I want. It's about the last If/else written.

When `$is_there_g="False"`, I wanna do this: *`"cat affy.txt | cut -d" " -f$columns"`*.

And if it's `True`, then: *`"grep $word affy.txt | cut -d" " -f$columns"`*.

I assess it using `"echo $is_there_g"` at the end of my code .

So the problem is that the results I obtain are always for a False case even though `"echo $is_there_g" gives me a True value`. Why???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need spaces around the operator:

```
if [ $is_there_g = "False" ]; then
```

[`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) or [`man test`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) for more information.

Comment: @user2886545: If that solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking the green check mark.